# css - stop inheritance of opacity

Tags: css, opacity

I have `div` with `opacity:0.80;` property that contain text and button. The problem is that button and text also inheritance opacity from `div`. How to fix it?

I already tried to add `opacity:1;` to button and text `<p>` tag, but it does not helps.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=css+background+opacity Some options: **1.** rgba **2.** element background and element content as adjacent elements **3.** transparent png image

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you want the opacity on the background instead. As Prisoner said, not supported by old browsers.

`background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);`

w3schools: RGBA color values are supported in IE9+, Firefox 3+, Chrome, Safari, and in Opera 10+.

Comment: check the compatibility of `rgba` before using it though - http://css-tricks.com/rgba-browser-support/

Answer (score 1):

you can't fixed it.Child elements also getting parent opacity

One solution is using rgba:

USE `:after` pseudo element

```
element:hover:after {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1); // black with opacity 0.1
}
```

Comment: what `:after` do and must i add it to container or to button?